# Зависает Kali Linux или начинает глючить экран

Tags: kali-linux

Я могу что то делать. Например смотреть видео или пользоваться какими либо программами. И может просто резко все остановиться. И нельзя будет воспользоваться ни клавиатурой не мышкой.
Поможет только перезагрузка. 
Или же все может стать так как на картинке [image: !!!!]но опять же поможет только перезагрузка

Comment: Ноутбук? ПК? Прикрепите вывод uname -a

Comment: Видеокарта Nvidia?

Comment: Да, видеокарта nvidia

Comment: Можно конечно драйвер обновить, но по всем признакам видеокарта умирает. Перегрев.

Comment: Я исправил уже проблему) а посчет перегрева я проверю

Comment: @Konner Ну так "Выберите ответ на собственный вопрос" -- кнопка внизу этой страницы и опишите как вы решили эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Все у кого видеокарта Nvidia и кто сталкивается с проблемами как у меня поможет это:
Полностью обновить линукс и убедиться, что у вас установлены заголовки ядра (kernel headers):

`apt-get update`
`apt-get dist-upgrade`

`apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

`apt-get install nvidia-kernel-dkms`

Далее отключаем nouveau:

`sed 's/quiet/quiet nouveau.modeset=0/g' -i /etc/default/grub`
`update-grub`
`reboot`

После перезагрузки проверяем работают ли драйверы:

`glxinfo | grep -i "direct rendering"`

должно появиться сообщение:
direct rendering: Yes

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте) Лучше всего  поставить версию с легким рабочим окружением, Arch, а именно - Manjaro, здесь уже задавался подробный  вопрос, можете почитать) https://codeby.net/threads/lagaet-kali-linux-2018-4.66230/

Comment: Есть принципиальные люди типа меня, которые хотят работать именно с тем окружением которое есть и ищут решение проблем теми или иными способами. Я мог так же установить ParrotSecurityOS и не париться, но такой выход не для меня)